# Issues with logout/login views

Tags: python, django

EDIT: So it seems the logout/`loginRequiredMixin` functionality works in my '/admin' page, so i think the problem lies with the button in my index.html

I am not able to log out of my account in my django app.  Or if i am, i am able to go to a view where login is required.

In other words, I am able to login correctly, but when i try to add logout functionality, it seems to do nothing, or the `LoginRequiredMixin` is not working correctly

views.py

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'APP/login.html'

    def post(self, request):
        email = password = ""
        state = ""

        if request.POST:
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            print(email, password)

            user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('email'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)

                return redirect('/login/index/')
            else:
                state = "Inactive account"
                # logging.StreamHandler
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'state': state, 'email': email})

class LogOutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'APP/logout.html'

    def logout(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/login')

class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'APP/index.html'
```

I currently have these in my urls.py

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', views.LogOutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('login/index/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/logout'
```

and my logout button is on my index.html page like so:

```
<a href="logout/">
        <button>logout</button>
</a>
```

I am not sure how to implement `LoginRequiredMixin` for it to work, and clicking the logout button doesn't seem to log out the user.

Comment: try printing `request.user` and `request.user.is_authenticated`. if `is_authenticated` returned `False` after you logout then the problem should be with  `LoginRequiredMixin` and if it still returned `True` then the `logout()` function didn't work or you didn't actually called it.

Comment: So it doesnt appear to be calling the logout() function when i go to the logout.html page, and i'm not sure why

Comment: it could be one of the two reason i think.  1. def logout(self, request): ; name of the function should be either get or post not logout 2. <a href="logout/">
        <button>logout</button>
</a>; try something like  <a href="logout/">
        logout
</a>

Comment: Well probably the `logout` function in your class doesn't gets called. try changing the name to 'get` so any get request to the page will call that function.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use forms like that. Check out `cleaned_data`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `get` method:

```
class LogOutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'APP/logout.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/login')
```